# Unable to calculate pay with javaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head> <title> Jessica Jones</title>
Pay Calculator
</head>
<br/> <br/>
<body>
<form>
Enter working hours: <input type="text" name="hours" size="10"> <br/> <br/>
Enter pay rate: <input type="text" name="rate" size="10"> <br/> <br/>

<input type="button" value="Show Me The Money" onclick="compute()" "  
function calculate() {
var h = document.forms(0).hours.value ;
var r = document.forms(0).rate.value ;
var gp = document.forms(0).gross pay.value ; 
var gp = h * r ;
result.value = gp
document.forms(0).grosspay.value = gp ;}
"> 
<br/> <br/>
Gross Pay: <input type="text" name="gross" size="10" readonly> <br/> <br/>
Tax amount: <input type="text" name="tax" size="10" readonly> <br/> <br/>
Net Pay: <input type="text" name="Pay" size="10" readonly> <br/> <br/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: The script should be put in a `script` tag

Comment: Where is `compute()` defined?

Comment: besides the script being in the wrong place, you call compute, but the function is called calculate, and this function refers to fields called hours, rate and gross pay, none of which exist, and the last one gross pay is invalid syntax due to the space

Comment: Also, `forms` is not a function. What you mean is not `forms(0)` but `forms[0]`.

Comment: I have made those changes and it is still not calculating.  How do you suggest to get the function to work correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Selecting form

```
var oForm = document.forms[1];
```

or

```
var oForm = document.getElementById("myForm")
```

Selecting form Elements

```
oForm.elements[index of element].value;
```

or

```
 oForm.elements["element Name"].value;
```

Comment: This answer doesn’t adress most of the question’s problems (e.g. invalid syntax) and contains mistakes itself (e.g. space after `oForm`, `forms[1]` instead of `forms[0]`).

Comment: copy past problem @Xufox